# Git Fix existing commits history

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a batch exe that script all database object and then automatically commit into a git repository.

For some reason ,that I've already fixed, actually i have this history:

- Commit 1: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...addedd
- Commit 2: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...modified
- Commit 3: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...deleted
- Commit 4: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added
- Commit 5: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...deleted
- Commit 6: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added
- Commit 7: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...modified

At commit 6, file is logically different from commit 4
But if i show file history i don't see nothing because the file is new for git system.

There is a way to solve this mess ?

I wish this history:

- Commit 1: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...addedd
- Commit 2: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...modified
- Commit 3: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...deleted --remove this
- Commit 4: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added   --set as change of commit 2
- Commit 5: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...deleted -remove this
- Commit 6: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added   --set as change of commit 4
- Commit 7: File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...modified

Thanks for your support

Comment: try to compare commit 4 with 3, what is the result?

Comment: @Hoshani comparing 4 and 3 sampleStoredProcedure.sql is an new file, commit 1/2/3 are not part of the file history

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i) to squash the commits where you deleted and re-added the file.

**I'd recommend making a backup of your repository before following the next steps.**

1. Get the ref of "Commit 1", e.g. `f79c595bce675cf6109ce9c7d477741a55a9a247`.
2. Run `git rebase --interactive <ref>`.
3. You should see a file with containing something like this:

```
pick f79c595 File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added
pick 141asd1 File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...modified
pick 6d2b123 File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...deleted
pick asd123a File sampleStoredProcedure.sql ...added
```

4. Change `pick` to `fixup` for all of the lines where the file was added again, i.e. with commit message "...added."
5. Save the file.
6. New files will be opened where you can edit the commit message of the new commits if you want to.

If you have many commits and your commit messages all have the same format, you can use a macro or script in your editor to find all of the relevant commits. As an example, here is how I would do it in Vim:

1. Start the interactive rebase with Vim `GIT_EDITOR=vim git rebase --interactive <ref>`.
2. Type: `qw/added<enter>^dwifixup <esc>jq:%normal @w<enter>`
3. Save and quit with `:wq`.

Comment: My repo has more than 2800 object in the largest database, and i have many databases repos with the same problem. Based on your knowledge, there is something more automatic that I can try. It would be enough for me to be able to see the history of the previous commits based on the file name

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with seeing the history of a file. Do you mean with `git blame` or what command do you use?

Comment: Cool. I can't think of any other way to do what you want to do then. Only additional recommendations I have is to use `fixup` instead of `squash` so that you won't have to manually edit the commit messages and to write a script or macro to automatically find the "added" commits in the interactive rebase. Will add an example Vim macro to the answer.